# Bricked Moto G2 XT1068 with a Cynogenmod with low battery.Need some help :)

Tags: cyanogenmod, charging, motorola-moto-g2

I have Moto G 2nd generation XT1068. I flashed my custom ROM and installed a CYNOGENMOD in my phone.It worked fine for 4 month and now its totally bricked.
I could enter fastboot mode but it shows low battery in fastboot mode, so i couldn't revert my phone back to normal. I m not much a techie, so hope for a solution in stepwise :)

Finally ,
 Bricked MOTO G2: cynogenmod installed : LOW BATTERY ==> SOLUTION please :)

Thanks.

Comment: TWRP recovery is able to handle charging; you should be able to boot into it from the bootloader, provided that you have flashed one.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the phone to pc, then entering bootloader(press all buttons)
Let it charge for a couple minutes, then reboot to recovery... or just reboot to recovery.
had this issue about half a year ago.